# Compute matrix of pairwise angles between two arrays of points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, distance

I have two vectors of points, `x` and `y`, shaped `(n, p)` and `(m, p)` respectively. As an example:

```
x = np.array([[ 0.     , -0.16341,  0.98656],
              [-0.05937, -0.25205,  0.96589],
              [ 0.05937, -0.25205,  0.96589],
              [-0.11608, -0.33488,  0.93508],
              [ 0.     , -0.33416,  0.94252]])
y = np.array([[ 0.     , -0.36836,  0.92968],
              [-0.12103, -0.54558,  0.82928],
              [ 0.12103, -0.54558,  0.82928]])
```

I want to compute an `(n, m)`-sized matrix that contains the angles between the two points, a la [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827393/angles-between-two-n-dimensional-vectors-in-python) question. That is, a vectorized version of:

```
theta = np.array(
            [ np.arccos(np.dot(i, j) / (la.norm(i) * la.norm(j)))
                 for i in x for j in y ]
        ).reshape((n, m))
```

Note: `n` and `m` can be of the order of ~10000 each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

```
import numpy.linalg as la
from scipy.spatial import distance as dist

# Manually
def method0(x, y):
    dotprod_mat = np.dot(x,  y.T)
    costheta = dotprod_mat / la.norm(x, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    costheta /= la.norm(y, axis=1)
    return np.arccos(costheta)

# Using einsum
def method1(x, y):
    dotprod_mat = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', x, y)
    costheta = dotprod_mat / la.norm(x, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
    costheta /= la.norm(y, axis=1)
    return np.arccos(costheta)

# Using scipy.spatial.cdist (one-liner)
def method2(x, y):
    costheta = 1 - dist.cdist(x, y, 'cosine')
    return np.arccos(costheta)

# Realize that your arrays `x` and `y` are already normalized, meaning you can
# optimize method1 even more
def method3(x, y):
    costheta = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', x, y) # Directly gives costheta, since
                                            # ||x|| = ||y|| = 1
    return np.arccos(costheta)
```

Timing results for (n, m) = (1212, 252):

```
>>> %timeit theta = method0(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.1 ms per loop
>>> %timeit theta = method1(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit theta = method2(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit theta = method3(x, y)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.42 ms per loop
```

The difference in timing reduces as the number of elements increases. For (n, m) = (6252, 1212):

```
>>> %timeit -n10 theta = method0(x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 365 ms per loop
>>> %timeit -n10 theta = method1(x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 358 ms per loop
>>> %timeit -n10 theta = method2(x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 384 ms per loop
>>> %timeit -n10 theta = method3(x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 314 ms per loop
```

However, if you leave out the `np.arccos` step, i.e., suppose you could manage with just `costheta`, and didn't *need* `theta` itself, then:

```
>>> %timeit costheta = np.einsum('ij,kj->ik', x, y)
10 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit costheta = 1 - dist.cdist(x, y, 'cosine')
10 loops, best of 3: 124 ms per loop
>>> %timeit costheta = dist.cdist(x, y, 'cosine')
10 loops, best of 3: 112 ms per loop
```

This is for the case of (6252, 1212). So actually `np.arccos` is taking up 80% of the time. In this case I find that `np.einsum` is *much* faster than `dist.cdist`. So you definitely want to be using `einsum`.

**Summary:** Results for `theta` are largely similar, but `np.einsum` is fastest for me, especially when you're not extraneously computing the norms. Try to avoid computing `theta` and working with just `costheta`.

**Note:** An important point I didn't mention is that finiteness of floating-point precision can cause `np.arccos` to give `nan` values. `method[0:3]` worked for values of `x` and `y` that hadn't been properly normalized, naturally. But `method3` gave a few `nan`s. I fixed this with pre-normalization, which naturally destroys any gain in using `method3`, unless you need to do this computation many many times for a small set of pre-normalized matrices (for whatever reason).

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I wonder why `dist.cdist` is so much slower. At these problem sizes, it's not likely to be function overhead.

Comment: Indeed. I'm not sure if my version of scipy is using BLAS properly though, so that might have something to do with it. I'd be interested to know if others get very different numbers.