# Calculate the angle between the rows of two matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, angle

I have two matrices consisting of 3d vectors (numpy 1D arrays) and  I need to calculate the angle between the vectors, row-wise, and return the results in a 1d array. I know how to calculate the angle between two 1d vectors. What is the the proper way to do this?

*** The resulting angles are in degrees not radians.

By now I have this:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,0,0],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,0,1]])

B = np.array([[1,0,1],
              [1,1,0],
              [0,1,0]])

def angle(V1,V2):
    """
    angle between vectors V1 and V2 in degrees using
    angle = arccos ( V1 dot V2 / norm(V1) * norm(V2) ) *180/np.pi
    """

    cos_of_angle = V1.dot(V2) / (np.linalg.norm(V1) * np.linalg.norm(V2)) 
    return np.arccos(np.clip(cos_of_angle,-1,1))  * 180/np.pi
```

*Note the scaling term 180/np.pi for the conversion from rad to deg.*

I would like to have an array:

```
C = [ angle(A[0],B[0]) , angle(A[1],B[1])...... and so on]
```

Really appreciated if someone could help.

Comment: The indentation and parenthesis looked wrong. Take a look and edit further if needed.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks @Divakar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could use [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to replace the dot-product computations and `axis` param for the `norm` ones to have a vectorized solution, like so -

```
def angle_rowwise(A, B):
    p1 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,B)
    p2 = np.linalg.norm(A,axis=1)
    p3 = np.linalg.norm(B,axis=1)
    p4 = p1 / (p2*p3)
    return np.arccos(np.clip(p4,-1.0,1.0))
```

We could optimize further and bring in more of `einsum`, specifically to compute `norms` with it. Hence, we could use it like so -

```
def angle_rowwise_v2(A, B):
    p1 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,B)
    p2 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',A,A)
    p3 = np.einsum('ij,ij->i',B,B)
    p4 = p1 / np.sqrt(p2*p3)
    return np.arccos(np.clip(p4,-1.0,1.0))
```

---

Hence, to solve our case to get output in degrees -

```
out = angle_rowwise(A, B)*180/np.pi
```

Comment: are these angles relative to the origin (0, 0, 0)? I am trying to translate the idea to using 3D points.

Comment: @NaN I am not really sure about the theory there. I was just focusing on translating it to a vectorized code.

Comment: it must be something different since you get different results than the implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827393/angles-between-two-n-dimensional-vectors-in-python a = np.array([[1, 0, 0],  [1, 0, 0],  [1, 0, 0]]) and b = np.array([[1, 0, 0],  [0, 1, 0], [0, -1, 0]]) to represent identical, same and opposite directional vectors pairing

Comment: @NaN That implementation looks different than the one posted by OP here. I am following this one here.

Comment: Dear friends, thank you for the kind help.I edited the original post, as  I have noticed I forgot to include the np.arccos in the return statement of the angle function. And as pointed by @Nan, I have included the  correction suggested at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827393/angles-between-two-n-dimensional-vectors-in-python) where a Nan would be returned in case of parallel vectors.

Comment: @RaphaelSantos So, are you sure about the `* 180/np.pi` that you are proposing in this question? I don't see that in the linked question.

Comment: @Divakar  the original post returned radians, the 180/np.pi is to convert to degrees... preference for explicit reading is simply np.degrees which does the same

Comment: @RaphaelSantos Edited answer.

Comment: @NaN and Divakar I can include np.degrees in the original post if you think it makes it easier for others to understand, otherwise I'll call it a wrap for now.

Comment: @RaphaelSantos Thin, you can just add in the question that the final output required is in degrees and hence that scaling with `180/np.pi`. Looks good otherwise.

Comment: To all.. deja vu https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54347/calculating-element-wise-the-angles-between-two-lists-of-vectors

Comment: @Divakar, still finding my way around here. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with 3D vectors, you can do this concisely using the toolbelt [vg](https://github.com/lace/vg). It's a light layer on top of numpy and it works equally well with individual vectors and stacks of vectors.

```
import numpy as np
import vg

A = np.array([[1,0,0],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,0,1]])

B = np.array([[1,0,1],
              [1,1,0],
              [0,1,0]])

vg.angle(A, B)
```

I created the library at my last startup, where it was motivated by uses like this: simple ideas which are verbose or opaque in NumPy.