# Python OpenCV Get Angle Direction of fitLine

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Using Python OpenCv, How does one find the Angle of fitLine through an element?
I am trying to use debugger and locate, since I do not see it here in documentation ,

```
rows,cols = img.shape[:2]
[vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(cnt, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
lefty = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
righty = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)
img = cv2.line(img,(cols-1,righty),(0,lefty),(0,255,0),2)
```

**Fitline References:**

[Fitline Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gaf849da1fdafa67ee84b1e9a23b93f91f)

[Open CV Tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contour_features/py_contour_features.html)

Not sure which items to acquire for slope in debugger

[image]

Comment: I haven't used it or tried it, but I guess it would be `arctan2((y2-y1)/(x2-x1))`

Comment: @MarkSetchell you have to be acreful using `tan` as if the angle maybe 90 degrees which in undefined for `tan`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have a unit vector that defines the direction of your line `[vx, vy]` from,

`[vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(cnt, cv2.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)`

Then if you are looking for the angle between your fitted line & the `x` axis you can use the dot product to get the angle,

```
import numpy as np

x_axis      = np.array([1, 0])    # unit vector in the same direction as the x axis
your_line   = np.array([vx, vy])  # unit vector in the same direction as your line
dot_product = np.dot(x_axis, your_line)
angle_2_x   = np.arccos(dot_product)
```

Comment: interesting that these answers are slightly different? are they off, just want to understand discrepancy, thanks 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849249/15435022   2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2827475/15435022

Comment: @mattsmith5 they are mathematically the same. The only difference is that they convert the vectors into unit vectors. We dont need to do that here as `cv2.fitLine` returns a unit vector (ie it does the conversion for you) & we are using a unit vector to represent the `x` direction.

Comment: dont forget to click that tick if this answer is working for you so other people can find it easily