# Getting angle between 2 vectors with the same starting point 2D

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, geometry, angle

I'm having some trouble with calculating the angle between 2 vectors with the same starting point - means there are 3 coordinates,

I have tried to define this func but it doesnt work when giving more then 1 vector:

```
def AngleBtw2Points(pointA, pointB):
    ang1 = np.arctan2(*pointA[::-1])
    ang2 = np.arctan2(*pointB[::-1])
    return np.rad2deg((ang1 - ang2) % (2 * np.pi))
```

[picture with example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkZAQ.png)

The input is (X0,Y0) (X1,Y1) (X2,Y2)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angles between two n-dimensional vectors in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827393/angles-between-two-n-dimensional-vectors-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using atan2 to find angle between two vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors)

Comment: was managed to fix it,
thank you. my function is:
def AngleBtw2Points(pointDES, pointSRC, pointA):
    ang = math.degrees(math.atan2(pointA[1]-pointSRC[1], pointA[0]-pointSRC[0]) - math.atan2(pointDES[1]-pointSRC[1], pointDES[0]-pointSRC[0]))
    return ang + 360 if ang < 0 else ang

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment, you can use the dot product fairly easily to get the angle between two vectors.

```py
def AngleBtw2Vectors(vecA, vecB):
    unitVecA = vecA / np.linalg.norm(vecA)
    unitVecB = vecB / np.linalg.norm(vecB)
    return np.arccos(np.dot(unitVecA, unitVecB))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def AngleBtw2Points(pointDES, pointSRC, pointA):
    ang = math.degrees(math.atan2(pointA[1]-pointSRC[1], pointA[0]-pointSRC[0]) - math.atan2(pointDES[1]-pointSRC[1], pointDES[0]-pointSRC[0]))
    return ang + 360 if ang < 0 else ang
```

This fixed my issue, thank you for you help :)

Comment: Not the best way... It is enough to use only one call of atan2 (look at @yann ziselman comment)